# How can I know whether my port is blocked by firewall or engaged with some other service

Tags: firewall, windows-xp, port

I want to know whether the below 3388 port is blocked by firewall or it is engaged with some other services.
Could you please suggest on this.

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

D:\Documents and Settings\32323>telnet xfjdd.og.com 3388
Connecting To xfjdd.og.com...Could not open connection to the
host, on port 3388: Connect failed

D:\Documents and Settings\32323>
```

Answer (score 1):

By no means a hard and fast rule but, typically, if it sits on the 'Connecting to...' message for a short while, it is blocked by the firewall; while if it instantly goes past that and says 'Connect failed', the server has actively decided not to respond (either because the port is not open, or the service rejects your initial connection).

An old Windows command-line app called PortQry (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310099) used to do the job quite nicely, with a `FILTERED` response for blocked by firewall and a `NOT LISTENING` response for server rejection.

Otherwise, you should familiarise yourself with Nmap (http://nmap.org/); it uses `FILTERED` when blocked by a firewall and `CLOSED` when the server rejects.